# How to import a .csv file to SQLite for Android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, csv

I have never used a database before, so bear with me. I am programming for the Android tablet and don't have one in my possession yet, but will be getting it within a week. I have a .csv file in Excel whose data I would like to use in my app. I am aware that Androids come with SQLite, but exactly what that is or how to use it is beyond me.

I'm going to work on learning about databases as I go, but first-- How do I get my csv file into SQLite? Can I do that from my PC or do I have to wait and do it on the tablet? What do I need to download to make this happen, what exactly and where do I need to type, etc... I need really basic instructions on doing this and everything I've found online has gone way over my head due to my complete lack of experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can [download SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) to you PC and tinker with it in the meantime. The import doesn't have to happen on the phone.

You can find many ways to do this process in [their wiki](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 ...
 BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
 String line = "";
 db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] colums = line.split(",");
                if (colums.length != 4) {
                    Log.d("CSVParser", "Skipping Bad CSV Row");
                    continue;
                }
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(3);
                cv.put(dbCol0, colums[0].trim());
                cv.put(dbCol1, colums[1].trim());
                cv.put(dbCol2, colums[2].trim());
                cv.put(dbCol4, colums[3].trim());
                db.insert(TABLE, null, cv);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   db.endTransaction();
```

#### How to read the CSV file

Copy *file.csv* into the assets folder, and read it like this:

```
String mCSVfile = "file.csv";
AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
InputStream inStream = null;
try {
     inStream = manager.open(mCSVfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

 BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
...
```